# Spring-boot and Spring-Kafka compatibility matrix

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am looking for a compatibility matrix of the different parts of the Spring framework.

More specifically, I am looking for the newest Spring-Kafka version that is compatible with Spring-boot 1.5.2.

I found an old compatibility matrix of Spring, but this matrix was from 2014 and therefore deprecated.

I am not concerned about Spring-Kafka and Apache Kafka client compatibility nor am I concerned about Apache Kafka java client and Kafka broker compatibility. This compatibility matrices are available here:

https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it says on the first link:

> All users with brokers >= 0.10.x.x are recommended to use spring-kafka version 1.3.x or higher due to its simpler threading model thanks to KIP-62.

This means all boot 1.5.x users. I have updated the project page to clarify it.

The current 1.5.x boot version is 1.5.17; 1.5.2 is extremely old.

The current 1.3.x version is 1.3.8.

Comment: Thank you, Gary. Thank you for updating the project page.

Comment: Hi, @gary-russell, can you share any stack: Kafka Broker/Client/Spring-Cloud-Stream ready to production? e.g I'm trying on Confluent Docker image containing: Kafka:2.2 and spring-cloud-stream:2.2.0.RELEASE?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on an old answer. The current spring-kafka 2.2.x version is 2.2.7.RELEASE. It will work fine with a 2.2 broker;. It uses the 2.0.1 client by default, which can talk to a 2.2 broker. If you want to override the kafka-clients version to 2.2.1, that's ok too, but if you use the embedded kafka broker for testing you will need to upgrade all the kafka jars, as explained in the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#deps-for-21x).

Comment: You are right, it's an old answer, but I thought reusing a topic where you participated was the ideal path. It's hard to find the Matrix in Kafka docs, perhaps it should be a paramount topic. Thanks @GaryRussell, for the update. I let you a note in Github issues channel https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1763