# Spring Boot, Spring-Kafka, and Spring-Cloud compatibility

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

My question is about Spring-Kafka and Spring Cloud compatibility.

I am using the following versions:

- Kafka Broker 1.0.2
- Spring Boot 1.5.2
- Spring Kafka 1.2.2
- Spring Cloud Stream Chelsea.SR2 ([Spring Cloud Stream
  Core 1.2.2.RELEASE](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-starters/releases/tag/vChelsea.SR2))

The compatibility between Spring-Kafka and Spring Boot was asked in a different [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462929/spring-boot-and-spring-kafka-compatibility-matrix) a few days ago. The [Spring-Kafka project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) was updated with more details about the compatibility. The project site states the following:

> All users with brokers >= 0.10.x.x (and all spring boot 1.5.x users) are recommended to use spring-kafka version 1.3.x

The [compatibility matrix](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/wiki/Kafka-Client-Compatibility) for Spring Cloud Stream and Spring-Kafka states that:

> Spring Cloud Stream 1.2.x is compatible with Spring-Kafka 1.2.x, 1.1.x.

The Spring-Kafka project page recommends me to upgrade to 1.3.X, but my version of Spring Cloud Stream is no compatible with Spring-Kafka 1.3.X.

I would prefer to upgrade my Spring-Kafka version to 1.3.8. But I do not want to break Spring Cloud Stream.

Does anyone have experience with using a newer version of Spring-Kafka with an older version of Spring Cloud Stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.5.2 is extremely old (early 2017). The current Boot 1.5.x version is 1.5.18 (released today).

If you start a new Spring Boot 1.5 project using [Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) You get

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.18.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring-kafka.version>1.3.8.RELEASE</spring-kafka.version>
</properties>
```

Edgware.SR5 pulls in the Ditmars Spring Cloud Stream release train (1.3.3) and, as you can see, spring-kafka 1.3.8 is used too.

So I would recommend you upgrade everything to get current.

Comment: I can upgrade Spring Boot to 1.5.17 - I have not tested with 1.5.18. I am using Spring Cloud Dalston.SR5, and I cannot upgrade this to a newer version.

Comment: Chelsea SR2 is ancient too; it would really be better to try to keep more current with all these libraries. That said, I just ran a test with it and overriding `kafka-clients` to 0.11.0.2 and a simple processor app (in/out) worked without any problems. YMMV.

Comment: Gary, thank you for the feedback. I am aware that it is very old, but I am stuck with the version.